# Bareiss Algorithm

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I need to find the row Echelon form of a large, (sparse,) integer matrix. It seems that the Bareiss algorithm is a prime candidate, but I can't find any resources beyond the Wikipedia page that provide a simple explanation of the algorithm. Are there any resources/recommended books that I should look into?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am learning this algorithm, too. Firstly, in the wiki page, the [original paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1968-22-103/S0025-5718-1968-0226829-0/S0025-5718-1968-0226829-0.pdf) of the algorithm is provided. Then, I found a valuabel C++ implementation from [NYU](http://cs.nyu.edu/exact/core/download/core_v1.4/core_v1.4/progs/bareiss/bareiss.cpp), which is readable and simple.

Comment: Note that the cited implementation from NYU claims to do pivoting, but it doesn't, and suffers from zero-divides.  See [Deanna Richelle Leggett's  thesis](http://www.math.usm.edu/perry/Research/Thesis_DRL.pdf) p.34 for an example and discussion of a standard workaround.

Comment: I want to add that her solution is incomplete.  One may need to swap columns as well as rows to avoid a situation in which none of the applicable rows with which to swap have a non-zero element in the relevant column.  In general, one might have to swap both rows and columns in a single step to get a non-zero element in the required position.  If there are no non-zero elements, then the determinant is zero.  Additionally, her $A^{(3)}$ on page 34 zeroes out $A_{21}$, $A_{31}$, and $A_{41}$, which is not specified by the algorithm on page 26, but does not affect the result of the calculation.

Comment: @DonHatch, thank you, it works.