# Jordan–Bareiss algorithm

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, computational-mathematics, python, sagemath

**Jordan–Bareiss Algorithm** is an algorithm that find determinant of $n \times n$ square matrix $M$. Its algorithm is given below:

1. Initialize the sign $s := 1$ and set $c := m^{(-1)}_{00}
    = 1;$
2. loop over rows $M_k$ of $M$ for $k ∈ \{1, \dots , n\}$:
   a) find the pivot $m_{ik} \neq 0$ with $i ≥ k$;
   b) if no such $m_{ik}$ exists, then return $0$ and quit;
   c) if $i \neq k$, then swap the rows $M_k$ and $M_i$ and update the sign, setting $s := −s$.
   d) replace every row $M_i$ with $i ∈ \{k + 1, \dots , n\}$ by an expression
   $\hspace{2.4cm}$ $\frac{(m_{kk}·M_i − m_{ik}·M_k)}{c}$
   e) update the divisor $c$ setting $c:= m_{kk}$;
3. return $\det M = s·m_{nn} $.

Here is my trial using SageMath but its giving wrong answer.

```
def JordanBarreiss(M):
    assert M.is_square(), "It must be a square matrix"
    n=M.dimensions()[0]
    s=1
    c=1
    for i in [1,..,n-1]:
        for k in [1,..,n-1]:
            if M[i,k] == 0 and i < k:
                return 0
            if i != k:
                M.swap_rows(i,k)
                s=-s
                for j in [k+1,..,n-1]:
                    M[j] = (M[k,k]*M[j] - M[j,k]*M[k])/c
        c = M[k,k]
    return M[n-1,n-1]
```

```
A = matrix(QQ, [[5,1,-9,0],[-1,3,-1,1],[8,-2,1,-3],[2,2,1,2]]);
JordanBarreiss(A);

out[110]  0

The expected output M = 5  1  -9   0 
                        0  16 -16  5
                        0  0   196 -30
                        0  0   0   475
where M[n-1,n-1] = 475 (det(M))
```

Please, it will be highly appreciated if anyone could help to fix this error, Python is also allowed. thanks.

Comment: You must begin by showing you have attempted something !!! Three remarks: 1) What is the meaning of $m_{ik}6=0$ ? 2) Besides, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python is a more indicated place 3) but it will surely be said there the same remark as my initial remark!

Comment: Why do you want to implement it anew and not use existing determinant functions?

Comment: @JeanMarie, thanks for your guide, I have now done as you guided. thanks

Comment: @ahulpke It is an Important assignment, please help, thanks.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I think because the first should row be excluded and the syntax is ok for Sagemath but i will be grateful if you can use Python too. you can check my new update about the question for the expected result. thanks

Comment: This question is about the technical and language-specific implementation of the algorithm.  Stack Overflow is a more appropriate site for that.  Here on Math.SE, we're more concerned about the mathematical properties of the algorithm, say its asymptotic behavior.

Comment: What is the meaning of $c := m^{-1}_{00} (−1)
 = 1$?

Comment: A related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2799578

Comment: @miracle173 It is an assumed initial pivot or a variable that stored previous pivot

Comment: In your program, why do you have j in [k+1,..,$\color{red}{n-1}$]: instead of  j in [k+1,..,$\color{red}{n}$]: ?

Comment: @G'Prime Yes, I think $m_{00}$ is the top left element of the matrix $M$. And $m^{-1}_{00}$ is $\frac 1 {m_{00}}$. But what is $m^{-1}_{00} (−1)$? Is this $\frac 1 {m_{00}}$ multiplied by $-1$? Why do you not write $-\frac 1 {m_{00}}$. And what is $m^{-1}_{00} (−1) = 1$. A boolean expression that you assign to $c$?

Comment: @JeanMarie with [k+1,..,n] the matrix index will go out of range, it must be n-1 according to indices rule

Comment: @miracle173, you can see it assumed to be c=1 for the beginning and see how its getting update from the loop.
thanks

Comment: As others have pointed out, Math SE is intended for questions about *mathematics*, not software.  My understanding of your question is that you are asking us to help you debug your code.  This is off-topic here.  If you have a *mathematical* question, please edit your post to clarify the nature of that question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Now I get it, thanks all

````
def JordanBarreiss(M):
    """
     JordanBareiss: Function to compute determinant of nxn square matrix M of size this algorithm
     
     INPUT:
        
         - A square matrix M
    
    OUTPUT:
        
        - det(M) 'determinant of the given matrix'

    """
    assert M.is_square(), "Only Square matrix allowed"
    n=M.dimensions()[0]
    c=1
    for k in range(n-1):
        for i in range(k+1,n):
            for j in [k+1,..,n-1]:
                M[i,j] = (M[i,j]*M[k,k] - M[i,k]*M[k,j])/c
        c=M[k,k]
    return M[n-1,n-1]

```
````